# flutter error when importing custom font

Tags: gradle, fonts, dart, yaml, flutter

I try to install an icon as a custom font but whenever I try to run my app the console tells me that I got an error in the pubspec.yaml file. My font location is: myapp/fonts/icomoon.ttf 
and this is the relevant part of the pubspec.yaml file:

```
 fonts:
  - family:          icomoon
     fonts:
     -asset:        fonts/icomoon.ttf
```

and the error message I got is:

> #/properties/flutter/properties/fonts/items/properties/fonts: type: wanted [array] got {-asset: fonts/icomoon.ttf} Error building assets
>   for
>   C:\Users\merli\Documents\Projects\WorkoutApp\myapp\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug/app.flx
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\merli\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 441
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Users\merli\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1

Comment: It might be caused by inconsistent indentation. Indentation in YAML matters. Check https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/fonts/ for how it should look like.

Comment: See https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts (and make sure you put the `fonts:` node under the top level `flutter:` node (and not, for example, under `dependencies > flutter`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indentation and formatting is very important when working with YAML (as Gunther already mentioned in his comment). I ran your snippet of code through [an online YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com) and found 2 issues:

- 1 extra space before `fonts:` that should not be there
- `-asset:` needs an extra space to be `- asset:`. Otherwise for YAML it is just a string that happens to start with `-`

The error you received tells you that even though an array was expected for `fonts`, something else was encountered (the second item on the above list).

Here is the correct form I ended up with:

```
 fonts:
  - family:          icomoon
    fonts:
     - asset:        fonts/icomoon.ttf
```

Comment: In case someone is following tutorials available online, make sure the assets path is correct. My ttf file was in lib/fonts/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same behavior when I was trying to add Roboto font like this:

```
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
        - weight: 700
```

I then realized that, I need to press the "Get packages" button (I'm using VSCode). So, once you add, make sure to click "Get packages" button.

Answer (score 1):

after adding your font assets, define it under the `assets` section of your `pubspec.yaml`,you should re build your project run
`flutter packages get` ,firstly
this worked for me..

Answer (score -1):

flutter:

generate: true

uses-material-design: true

assets:

```
- assets/images/
- assets/go-logo.png
- assets/fb-logo.png
```

fonts:

```
- family: icomoon
    -asset icomoon.ttf
- family: Pacifico
    fonts
    -asset Pacifico-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Consider adding some information around this answer to make it useful, why or how does this solve the issue?